# Why Records are not able to pass as TestCase in Nunit

Tags: c#

I have a record with 2 params in it, its a compiler error while trying to pass the record as a `TestCase()`.

```
    [Test]
    [TestCase( myRecord)] // here it complains 
    public void StartGame_SingleValidGame( MyRecord  myRecord)
    {
        var result = myObject.Foo(myRecord);
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }


    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var a = new Rec1("Abce", 0);
        var b = new Rec2("Xyz", 0);
        myRecord = new MyRecord(a, b);
    }
```

Does NUnit support `Records` ? or there were some issue while I fill the records in `[SetUp]` function ?

Comment: Your example is both incomplete and unnecessarily complicated due to having both a parameter and (by the looks of it, but you haven't shown it) a field called `myRecord`)

Answer (score 0):

There's only a handful of types that can be used as arguments to attributes, This isn't a Nunit thing, it's a c# thing.

from [Attribute parameter types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#2124-attribute-parameter-types):

> The types of positional and named parameters for an attribute class
> are limited to the attribute parameter types, which are:
>
> One of the following types:
>
> - bool, byte, char, double, float, int, long, sbyte, short, string,    uint, ulong, ushort.
> - The type object.
> - The type System.Type.
> - Enum types.
> - Single-dimensional arrays of the above types.
> - A constructor argument or public field that does not have one of these    types, shall not be used as a positional or named parameter
>   in an    attribute specification.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute parameters must be

- A constant value
- A `typeof` expression
- A single-dimensional array of the above values

If you want to use your variable in your test case, just use a field.

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyRecordTest
{
    private MyRecord myRecord

    [Test]
    public void StartGame_SingleValidGame()
    {
        var result = myObject.Foo(myRecord);
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var a = new Rec1("Abce", 0);
        var b = new Rec2("Xyz", 0);
        myRecord = new MyRecord(a, b);
    }
}
```